# Set configuration keyboard on AlertDialog

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to set the configuration of the keyboard only numeric when the user change the default value of "100", but appear the full text keyboard always!

```
 // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                                final EditText input = new EditText(appContextDialog);
                                input.setText("100");
                                input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);// tastiera Numerica
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(appContextDialog)
                                                                        .setTitle("Inserisci Quantita'")
                                                                        .setMessage(clickedItemString)
                                                                        .setView(input)
                                        .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.btn_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        Editable value = input.getText(); 

                                        userAdapter.UpdateIng(value.toString(), clickedItemString, TotVar); 
                                        userAdapter.UpdateBilanciamento(TotVar);
                                        UpdateImageAndTotal();
                                    }
                                        }).setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.btn_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        // Do nothing.
                                    }
                                }).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or TYPE_CLASS_PHONE for  setRawInputType property.
In XML you can use android:inputType="number" or "phone".

Follow these

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Ciao!